# Ruby how to reverse display order

Tags: ruby

I have code below:

```
def number_loop(n)
  puts "#{n}"
  while n != 1
   if  n >1
     n -= 1
     puts "#{n}"
   else
     n += 1
     puts "#{n}"
   end
  end
end

number_loop(5)
```

---

when I ran the code, it displayed as below:

5

4

3

2

1

how to change the code so that it will display as:

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: `1.upto(5).each { |number| puts number }`

Comment: Thank you Andrey! I am a beginner, do you mind explain a bit of the code you wrote? I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. There is a method in `Integer` class, called [`upto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto). What it does, is iterating the provided block (`{ |number| puts number }`) passing the integers starting from (in our case) `1` up until the passed argument to `upto` (in our case `5`). And the result is printing each number from 1 to 5

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Another way: `puts (1..5).map(&:itself)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using a `while` loop is rare and almost never seen in Ruby.
- When working with numbers use `upto` and `downto` methods or a range.
- When working with objects use `each` and `reverse_each`.

Using `Integer` methods

```
1.upto(5).each { |n| puts n } # => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
5.downto(1).each { |n| puts n } # => 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

1.step(5, 2).each { |n| puts n } # => 1, 3, 5
5.step(1, -2).each { |n| puts n } # => 5, 3, 1

5.times { |n| puts n } # => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Using a range

```
(1..5).each { |n| puts n } # => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

And if you work with objects use

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

arr.each { |str| puts str } # => a, b, c, d, e
arr.reverse_each { |str| puts str } # => e, d, c, b, a
```

And use `map` if you want to collect the results in an array

```
squares = (1..5).map { |n| n * n }
# => [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

For more browse the methods of

- `Integer` class
- `Enumerable` module

And best install `pry` to explore these interactively with Pry's `ls` and `ri` commands.